# Build errors in VS13 in angular.d.ts and jquery.d.ts using TypeScript

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, typescript, build-error

I'm trying to create an SPA application using AngularJS and Typescript in Visual Studio 2013.

It won't build, https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvDSn.png, saying angular.d.ts, jquery.d.ts and angular-route.d.ts contains builderrors.

VS gives me 249 errors, and TsLint 215 messages.

Is it possible to configure TsLint to not validate these files? Or am I on a completely wrong track, and something else causing the problem.

```
/// <reference path="../Scripts/typings/angularjs/angular.d.ts" />
module Application {
    "use strict";

    export class AngularApp {
        public static Module: ng.IModule = angular.module("app", []);
    }
}
```

Also, I'm getting an error saying that angular is not defined. I'm suspecting that this is caused by the build errors.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of TypeScript (1.4) https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2d42d8dc-e085-45eb-a30b-3f7d50d55304

Comment: This solved the problem, thanks :) Apparently I was running an older version of Typescript.

Comment: Glad it worked. I'll close this with reference to the first question that was related to this issue.